# how to reduce the quality of pdf created using R

Tags: r, pdf-generation, pdftk

I am creating pdf reports using R (command *?pdf*).
The reports contain images that I have created and that are quite heavy (lot of datapoints)
The created pdfs are very heavy. Is there a way to reduce the quality of the pdf when creating it?

I know I can do it using *pdftk* but I'd rather do it in one go as I want to minimize the number of manual operations.

Comment: Manual operations? That's what shell scripts are for.

Comment: @Will Hartung: can I call pdftk in a system() function in R?
Maybe, but still... If possible it would be cleaner to specify the quality when creating the pdf rather than changing it afterwards!

Comment: if you can call it from a command line, you can call it from system(). As long as you don't need to send mouseclicks or some GUI actions, it's simple and straightforward.

Comment: Yes I use system("pdftk.exe pdf1 output pdf2 compress"). It reduces by 50% my pdf...

Comment: Good to hear, hope that help solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your PDF has a large number of data points sometimes a raster presentation is more efficient.  You lose the infinite zoom of a vector format but can have a very nice representation for print or normal viewing sizes.  It may also render faster.

Try generating your graphic in PDF and raster formats and see which is more efficient / suits your needs.  You might be surprised that a PNG makes you happier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll will certainly do that. By in the end I would like to have a pdf. Do you know if it is possible to include a png inside the pdf? (without creating first the png then concatening)

Comment: I suppose for PDF embedding jpeg is probably best just because it's the most compatible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no other solution than calling pdftk:
(extract from ?pdf)

```
pdf writes uncompressed PDF. It is primarily intended for producing 
PDF graphics for inclusion in other documents, and PDF-includers such 
as pdftex are usually able to handle compression: there are a large 
number of PDF compression utilities such as pdftk.
```